# Reloading same page in a Vue SPA site

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've tried over a dozen ways to do this. `.htaccess` in an apache hosting (my preferred environment where I have my site hosted), Through heroku, through netlify with a `_redirects` file and `netlify.toml` file. And none of them seem to work. Vue recommends to write the `.htaccess` file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't reload to the same page. It reloads to the main index.html page. Now, I get it why is doing that. In essence, every page in an SPA is an index.html. It's the components that make it look like a different page. However, this works in every SPA site I've seen. So there's gotta be a way for the render to remain consistent when I reload.

In case it matters, here is some related code

ENVIRONMENT

- VueJS 2
- Quasar 1.0
- Firebase
- Vuew router (out of the box in VueJS)

QUASAR.CONF.JS

```
  build: { vueRouterMode: "history" }
```

ROUTES.JS (minimal)

```
import Layout from "layouts/Layout.vue";
import Home from "pages/Index.vue";
import About from "pages/About.vue";
import Contact from "pages/Contact.vue";


const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Layout,
    children: [
      { path: "/", component: Home },
      { path: "/about", component: About },
      { path: "/contact", component: Contact }
    ]
  }
];

// Always leave this as last one
if (process.env.MODE !== "ssr") {
  routes.push({
    path: "*",
    component: () => import("pages/Error404.vue")
  });
}

export default routes;
```

If there is anything you need to see, let me know.

PROBLEM
The page loads fine, but when I reload a page, it loads the main page (HOME) which is the index page. Without the htaccess code it shows a Page not found (not even my own 404). History mode removes the # from the URL and putting it in Hash mode doesn't fix it either.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you saying that even when the Vue app in on a route eg www.yoursite.com/#/about a page refresh takes you to your 'index' page instead of the about page? Assuming you have an about page of course

Comment: @CoderLee correct.

Comment: Have you tried removing the the .htaccess and other rules? You should only need apache2, or whichever server you're using, to serve the index HTML and let the JS handle the rest. It sounds like something is forcing your URL back to the index or overwriting your current route.

Comment: Removing the htaccess breaks it. It shows a 404 instead of re-routing (to even the main page). I explained that in the question too. Besides, when I set up an htaccess rule, it goes in the main root for the whole site. not just one page. I'm hosting with Dreamhost

Comment: Have you tried removing the catch all for 404 in your Vue app? Maybe the path:'*' is catching every route. Sounds like something is doing that.

Comment: It also happens in netlify and heroku with their respective redirect files

Comment: That sounds odd, I use Netlify frequently and haven't needed a _redirect file. The initial setup has always been enough, is there a particular reason you need it over the initial/base setup they offer?

Comment: Since it's always on the index.html I'm willing to bet the rewrite rule(s) are overriding the route and sending your requests to the index.html every time. Maybe try not using them or being more verbose so they don't catch the index every time.

Comment: Just found this, hopefully it'll help you out: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert my app from hashes to history without problem by setting the mode and router in the routes file (src/routes/index.js in my setup):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    component: NotFound,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

By setting the mode and exporting the router I was able to resolve the 404 issue from my application. However, Quasar might be doing something else under the hood. Hopefully this approach can lend itself to yours.

Comment: history mode is already implemented in quasar.conf. I am able to verify this by seeing the hashbang disappear. I also explained that in my question. I am defining the router in an index.js that imports the route.js you see in my question. So basically it's the same thing I have, only I have it split into 2 different files

Comment: You have everything Quasar and Vue recommends. It's a head scratcher as to why it's not working. Maybe try setting the history mode in Vue instead of Quasar if it'll let you. It's a shot in the dark, but the recommended setup isn't working anyways.

Comment: yeah, tried that too lol... I'm telling you. I've tried everything imaginable

Comment: I believe it haha, that's obnoxious to say the least. Please share if you figure it out, because there has got to be something crazy bugging out your Quasar or Vue.